# CMake: rewrite project, only if modified?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a CMake project which generates several Visual Studio projects into a single solution. If I make a change to the CMake scripts, which only affects a single project (for example, `add_target_definitions`) and call CMake to regenerate the projects, all of the project files (*.vcxproj) are rewritten to disk. This triggers a rebuild of all targets, even though perhaps only one of the project files is actually different than it was. This adds greatly to the build time of the different configurations I have.

I would like to rebuild only a few projects with these different target defines (eg. supplied on the command line), and not recompile the unaffected libraries. I also require a solution which works when compiling the `ALL_BUILD` target, and does not split the project into multiple projects (solutions).

Is there a CMake option, or some other trick to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that CMake script I was using `add_target_definitions` in was included in the CMakeLists.txt at the top level, and thus, all CMakeLists.txt in directories below it were a dependency of it. I found this by inspecting the `generated.stamp.depend` for one of the projects.

If I split this out into a separate script that is only included by the project which requires it, the projects are no longer rewritten.

Comment: Could you clarify / elaborate your answer? I could not understand it. What is generated.stamp.depend? where is it? What was slowing the regeneration and how did you fix it?