# Is there a way to invoke cmake only on modified targets?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

I am working on a large C++ cmake project that contains many targets.

My current workflow is to configure cmake, generate a Visual Studio solution and work on it as if it was a standard Visual Studio solution.

This workflow is inefficient. Especially when compared to working on a non-cmake project on Visual Studio.

Each time I modify a single cmake target - such as adding a file, changing the the target `CMakeList.txt` in some way, the `ZERO_CHECK` target triggers cmake reconfiguration and generation.

This is rather slow and annoying. I must wait for configuration of **ALL TARGETS**, even the ones I did not change and have no dependency whatsoever on my modified target. For a large project this can take minutes.

I know I can disable the `ZERO_CHECK` target by adding `set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION true)` to the root `CMakeLists.txt`. But this will force me to invoke cmake manually - which I don't mind but I don't think it will be any more efficient than what `ZERO_CHECK` is doing.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to invoke cmake only on modified / affected targets? Or maybe trigger a 'partial' regeneration?
2. Is there a general way to make cmake regeneration faster in the particular case of modifying a single target?

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660244/cmake-rewrite-project-only-if-modified)

Comment: I doubt there is anything in CMake which will give you what you want; it just reruns the script, how could it possibly know if it should run just part of the script? The problem, in my opinion, lies in the time it takes. If the project configuration takes so much time then that time should be addressed.

Comment: There is no doubt it should be addressed. But some things are outside of my immediate control. The fact that cmake works in a manner of "pay for what you don't have to" is a problem too in my opinion.

Comment: CMake isn't the best piece of software, that's for sure. But we have what we have and I'd not expect for it to change drastically any time soon.

Comment: You could theoretically try to separate some parts of the project to separate cmake projects that are configured independently and are installed locally in a way that allows you to use `find_package` from the project using the targets. This way you could update the subprojects and unless the cmake configuration scripts change, you'd end up with.

Comment: Another thing that could speed up things is caching some results, e.g. if you've got a lot of `try_compile`s caching the results and not repeating the check could significantly speed things up and if you choose the variable names well, you could clear them easily using the `-U` command line option with the appropriate pattern, if needed.

Comment: Regarding configuration speed: if you have multiple equal `find_package` calls in more than one directory, consider moving them outside. This trick boosted configuration time from ~2 minutes to ~20 seconds on a large project (~200 targets, ~7k files).

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but you could try using the `--profiling-output` and `--profiling-format` arguments of [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) to get insight on configuration operation times. [clion has some wriitng about these flags too](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profiling.html).